# Link style with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for hiding\showing link depends on state of cBoxoverlay. But when i click to close this item(`display:none`), and then click again to show it(`display:block`) my link(`#close-news`) still not showing.

```
jQuery(document).click(function () {
  if (jQuery("#cBoxOverlay").css("display", "none")) {
    jQuery("#close-news").css("display", "none");
  } else if (jQuery("#cBoxOverlay").css("display", "block")) {
    jQuery("#close-news").css("display", "block");
```

Where did i make mistake?

Comment: Seems to me like you are not checking a condition in the if statement but setting the display properties to none and block.. could that be the issue ?

Comment: no idea, im totally new to JS, but have to make it work ASAP

Comment: well then, @Raminson's answer is good to go with..

Comment: none of posted below really worked for me.

Comment: which version of JQuery are you using ?

Comment: 1.4.4 i guess, the one that in core of drupal 7.13. Also its in protected mode, so i have to use jQuery instead of $

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14418/discussion-between-avdept-and-code90)

Answer (score 1):

try this - no need for if statements.  You can just set the `#close-news` to whatever `#cBoxOverLay` is

```
$(document).click(function () {        
    $("#close-news").css("display", $("#cBoxOverlay").css('display'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if ($("#cBoxOverlay").css("display") == "none") {
  // ...
}
```

however you can use `is` method:

```
if ( $("#cBoxOverlay").is(':hidden')) {
       // ...
}
```

---

```
 $(document).click(function(){
   if ($("#cBoxOverlay").is(":hidden")) { // if #cBoxOverlay is hidden
       $("#close-news").hide() // hide the #close-news
    } else if ($("#cBoxOverlay").is(":visible")) { // if #cBoxOverlay is visible
       $("#close-news").show() // // show the #close-news
    }
 })
```

you can remove the the second condition and use `else` instead as when element is not hidden it is visible, of course.

Comment: @Avdept yes, check the updated answer, you can use `show()` and `hide()` which are same as css `display: block and none.`

Comment: Why say `is:hidden else is:visible`?  `is:hidden else` is enough :)

Comment: @Archer yes, point was clarifying how `:visible` and `:hidden`selectors work :).

Comment: @Raminson - thanks, I understand.  I was just clarifying that he doesn't need them both :)

Answer (score 0):

Use classes, does a cleaner job.

In case you don't want to use classes, try to use jQuery's toggle, which does basically exactly what you try to achieve: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, based on @Raminson's answer:

```
$(document).click(function () {
  if ($("#cBoxOverlay").is(':hidden')) {
    $("#close-news").css("display", "none");
  } else{
    $("#close-news").css("display", "block");
```

May be give a try on this one, too:

```
$(document).click(function(){
$('#close-news').css('display', function(){return $('#cBoxOverlay').css('display');});
});
```

Comment: the last one actually worked for me, but after 2nd click. Im clicking on image to pop up mylightbox, and then have to click one more time to show (#close-news), same when closing my lightbox window

Answer (score 0):

Use is(":visible") to check if the element is visible, and then either show or hide...

```
jQuery(document).click(function () {
    if (jQuery("#cBoxOverlay").is(":visible")) {
        jQuery("#close-news").hide();
    } else {
        jQuery("#close-news").show();
    }
});
```